# How to save two overlapping images to one in C# gtk# mono?

Tags: c#, image, mono, gtk#

I have made a window containing a Fixed container with two images .Here both images are dynamically set Images using Pixbuf. The two Images are overlapping . Like a frame and image .
How can I merge these images in one Image and save to the file system? Please help me I am new to this . Thanks

```
image12.Pixbuf = global::Gdk.Pixbuf.LoadFromResource ("TryNew.ivy.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](http://buttle.shangorilla.com/1.1/handlers/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGdk.Pixbuf), you will create a Pixbuf composite. The example there gives side-by-side images, but it would be the same principle for overlaying a frame on your picture.